# Select group of rows consisting of exactly one specific item

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Am working on one analysis where I want to get a certain product that was bought in my **item table**. Let's say I have this data:

| ProductId | ProductName | OrderId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tshirt | 1 |
| 4 | Lipstick | 1 |
| 4 | Lipstick | 2 |
| 6 | Jeans | 3 |
| 4 | Lipstick | 3 |
| 4 | Lipstick | 4 |
| 1 | Tshirt | 5 |
| 6 | Jeans | 5 |
| 4 | Lipstick | 5 |

How to get the complete Order that has a purchase of only Lipstick?

Output should be like this:

| ProductId | ProductName | OrderId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Lipstick | 2 |
| 4 | Lipstick | 4 |

Comment: We select **rows**  not items. Be careful how you phrase your question and what you assume. If an order contains many rows (presumably different) of lipsticks, what does your resultset contain / represent? You assume that an "order" has a single row for lipstick as do some of the answers. Your sample data is consistent with that assumption. Beware - real life is never so "neat".

Comment: @SMor, I need to get an order  that has one purchase in it which is Lipstick & if the order contains this item and many other item it could be stored under different row no. Hence, I was keen to get this particular item and am aware of what am asking here. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can check if for any order item, no other item exists:

```
SELECT *
FROM t AS t1
WHERE ProductName = 'Lipstick'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM t AS t2
    WHERE t2.OrderId = t1.OrderId
    AND t2.ProductName <> 'Lipstick'
)
```

Explanation: the outer query selects all *lipstick* order items. This will return order #1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. Lets call these rows lipstick order items.

The sub query then, for each row in lipstick order items, selects related order items (t2.OrderId = t1.OrderId) that do not contain lipstick (t2.ProductName <> 'Lipstick'). If no such row exists then the lipstick order item is unique.

Comment: Hi @Salman A, would you mind to share some details on the output of this query and how it works :)?

Comment: I have added explanation.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to get a list of orders that include *only* lipstick:

```sql
SELECT OrderId
FROM   Item
GROUP
    BY OrderId
HAVING Min(ProductName) = 'Lipstick'
AND    Max(ProductName) = 'Lipstick'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve only those product where previous row product and current product are same. That's why using lag() function for getting previous rows product.

```
SELECT t.ProductId, t.ProductName, t.OrderId 
FROM (SELECT *
           , LAG(ProductId) OVER (ORDER BY OrderId) prev_product
      FROM item) t
WHERE t.ProductId = t.prev_product
    AND t.ProductName = 'Lipstick'
```

Another way using previous and current row order

```
SELECT t.ProductId, t.ProductName, t.OrderId 
FROM (SELECT *
           , LAG(OrderId) OVER (ORDER BY OrderId) prev_order
      FROM item) t
WHERE t.OrderId != t.prev_order
    AND t.ProductName = 'Lipstick'
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=8cf359bb9bd73fd9fc9b4726117ff872

As per data retrieve even orderid.

```
SELECT *
FROM item
WHERE ProductName = 'Lipstick'
    AND OrderId % 2 = 0
```

N.B.: But I recommend first option only.

Comment: Negative vote with proper explanation is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, using conditional aggregation

```sql
SELECT i.OrderId
FROM Item i
GROUP BY
  i.OrderId
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN ProductName = 'Lipstick' THEN 1 END) > 1
  AND COUNT(CASE WHEN ProductName <> 'Lipstick' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Comment: True, have modified

Answer (score 0):

You can structure the query in such a way that it can show you all the orders that contain a single item, then you can decide which item to retrieve, assuming this item is not always going to be 'Lipstick'. Also real-life databases are often complex and you might have an OrderId with multiple rows of a single item. In that case you will need a distinct count. This can be done in multiple ways but will show two options.

**Preparing the database**

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (ProductId INTEGER, 
                        ProductName VARCHAR(100), 
                        OrderId INTEGER);

INSERT INTO tablename VALUES
  (1, 'Tshirt', 1),
  (4, 'Lipstick', 1),
  (4, 'Lipstick', 2),
  (6, 'Jeans', 3),
  (4, 'Lipstick', 3),
  (4, 'Lipstick', 4),
  (1, 'Tshirt', 5),
  (6, 'Jeans', 5),
  (4, 'Lipstick', 5);
```

**Option 1: Using Cross Apply**

```
WITH Product_count AS (
SELECT t1.*, t2.cnt
FROM tablename t1 CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t2.ProductName) AS cnt
      FROM tablename t2
      WHERE t2.OrderId = t1.OrderId 
     ) t2
)
SELECT ProductId, ProductName, OrderId
FROM Product_count
WHERE cnt = 1 AND ProductName = 'Lipstick';
```

**Option 2: Using Window Functions**

```
WITH Product_count AS (
SELECT *,
     DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderId ORDER BY ProductName)  
     + DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderId ORDER BY ProductName DESC) - 1 AS cnt
FROM tablename
)
SELECT ProductId, ProductName, OrderId
FROM Product_count
WHERE cnt = 1 AND ProductName = 'Lipstick';
```